# Create an associative array after .split ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

I take the example from the developer.mozilla.org official documentation so you can answer it more easily:

```
var names = "Harry Trump; Fred Barney; Helen Rigby; Bill Abel; Chris Hand";
var re = / \ s *; \ s * /;
var nameList = names.split (re);
```

This regular expression produces an array formed by the various elements divided by the character `;`.

My problem is this: I would like to associate with the array that is out of the element from which it was extracted, that is, `;`.
Basically the goal is to get something like this:

```
[
  {
  ";": ["Harry Trump"]
  },
   { 
  ";": ["Fred Barney"]
   }
  ...
]
```

instead of

```
[ "Harry Trump", "Fred Barney" , ... ]
```

Would you like to tie them up?

Comment: Your `Var` keyword should never start with an uppercase. It should be `var`. And also you need an array of objects.

Comment: What you want is not valid, do you want: `[
  {";": ["Harry Trump"]}, 
  {";": ["Fred Barney"]}  
]`

Comment: To do this you'd need to use an object as JS has no concept of associative arrays. Secondly, there's some issues. `Var` should be `var`, the 'regular expression' is completely invalid syntax, and your original string has no `;` characters in it

Comment: Google Translator Changed Automatically var in Var My Google Guilty Not My.

Comment: @User might be you need to use loop

Comment: There is no `;` in `names`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your separator is variable you can do this way

```js
let names = "Harry Trump, Fred Barney, Helen Rigby, Bill Abel, Chris Hand"
let re = /\s*(,)\s*/
let res = names.split(re).map(
  (currentValue, index, array) => {
    if (index%2!=0) {
      return {
        [currentValue]: (array[index-1] )
      }          
    }
  }
)
.filter((n)=>n)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/fq3238ku/1/

```js
var names = "Harry Trump, Fred Barney, Helen Rigby, Bill Abel, Chris Hand";

var splitName = names.split(',');

var data = [];
for(var i in splitName){
 data[i] = {";" : [splitName[i]]};
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is simply not possible. Once you have a value under key `;` then assigning another value will simply overwrite the previous one.

Comment: What's up with the downvoting?

Comment: Firstly, this is more of a comment than an answer. Secondly, it is possible, but the object schema needs to be changed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it answers the question and it is not possible in the way the OP requested it.

Comment: Well given the OP's code isn't valid in the first place (as it's an array, not an object as your answer implies) then they seem to be asking 'how can this be done', not necessarily 'can I do it like this'.